# Selecting some field after using distinct in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I want to use distinct in linq. After i use disctinct i don't select any field. Is it possible to select after distinct.

```
  query.select(x=>x.FirmName).Distinct().Select(x => new InvoiceSumReportrModel { Firma = x.FirmName, Id = x.Id,Country=x.Country }).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: You strip out everything except firmname in the first select, so no, you can't get the others back later in the chain. What are you _really_ trying to achieve?

Comment: You might want to clarify what your problem is. What error are you getting? I assume that the problem is that you are selecting Firmname in the first select and that the next select you expect the original object instead?

Comment: check if the .Distinct().Count() is upper  > 0 first

Comment: The query doesn't make sense. You're first selecting FirmName, then getting the distinct. So at this stage you have a single value of FirmName (presumably a string). You then take that and select x.FirmName and x.Id and x.Country. But at that stage 'x' is the FirmName. I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: Ah sorry, just noticed that @JoachimIsaksson said the same in his comment - so please ignore this :) I'll leave it there incase it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `Distinct`, you can use `GroupBy` to create a group for each FirmName, then grab the first firm from each group and project it to an `InvoiceSumReportModel`...

```
query.GroupBy(x => x.FirmName,
              (k, g) => g.Select(
                x => new InvoiceSumReportrModel 
                { 
                    Firma = x.FirmName, 
                    Id = x.Id,
                    Country = x.Country 
                })
                .First());
```